# how to give an expression for 2 dimenional json array

Tags: json, performance, jmeter-5.0

I need to get the all rid's which we have common IDs type ID 1182

```
{
  "Master": "SMaster",
  "Field": [
  "rid",
  "sid",
  "sname",
  "stype",
  "isPrimary"

],
"Data": [
[
  150986,
  55,
  "PERF_01",
  1182,
  1
],
[
  150987,
  55,
  "PERF_01",
  1182,
  1
],
[
  150988,
  55,
  "PERF_01",
  1187,
  1
]
 
   ],
    "ErrorCode": "0",
    "ErrorMsg": "",
    "Next": "0"
    }


$..[?(@.data[*][2]==1182)].data[0][0]
```